# command for obtaining the list of currently running applications on windows

Tags: java, command-line, windows-xp

I need to obtain the list of the currently running applications on windows using command or java program. for example if MS-Word and Window media player are the applications currently running on the system, then i want the list of these applications using a command or a java program.

Thanks and regards
Vivek Birdi

Answer (score 1):

For windows

```
WMIC /OUTPUT:C:\ProcessList.txt PROCESS get Caption,Commandline,Processid
```

Try executing this command from java that will list all currently running process on the file specified
[Here is an example how to execute command from java](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.lang/how-to-execute-a-command-from-code.html)

FYI:

for linux:

```
ps aux | less
```

Alternatively you can also use this ready made code for windows:

```
public static List<String> listRunningProcesses() {
    List<String> processes = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
      String line;
      Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("tasklist.exe /fo csv /nh");
      BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader
          (new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
      while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
          if (!line.trim().equals("")) {
              // keep only the process name
              line = line.substring(1);
              processes.add(line.substring(0, line.indexOf(""")));
          }

      }
      input.close();
    }
    catch (Exception err) {
      err.printStackTrace();
    }
    return processes;
  }
```

source :http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0593.html

Comment: Hi, this program lists all the processes running currently, But I need Applications only.

Comment: @user291977 from process you can determine app running. like if there is `firefox.exe` running that means firefox app is running